# On a new Ubuntu Server 20.04 install I can't connect to anything via my local network, i.e. Ping, SSH, etc. what steps should I take now?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 20.04. It's been a while since I've used Ubuntu and I'm at a loss on how to troubleshoot this next. My goal is, I'm trying to install Octoprint. I have it installed and running but I'm having a network issue that is driving me crazy.

Everything is installed and appears to be running correctly however, I cannot ping the Ubunutu server, nor connect with SSH, nor access Octoprint from the network. I can access the internet from the Ubuntu server, I can install/update packages, I can ping to external addresses, both IPs and domain names. I can also ping my gateway.

What I've tried so far:

I've tried allowing traffic to ssh with:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

I've tried disabling the firewall with:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

I've rebooted all the machines involved including the router and access point.

If it helps, when I ping from my Windows machine, the response shows it coming from my Windows machine's IP address instead of the Ubuntu address, if that matters.

What can I do to troubleshoot this next?

**EDIT: Adding requested info:**

**Ping from Windows 10 on the same subnet:**

> Pinging 192.168.0.127 with 32 bytes of data:
>
> Reply from 192.168.0.71: Destination host unreachable.
>
> Reply from 192.168.0.71: Destination host unreachable.
>
> Reply from 192.168.0.71: Destination host unreachable.
>
> Reply from 192.168.0.71: Destination host unreachable.
>
> Ping statistics for 192.168.0.127:
> Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

*Note: 192.168.0.71 is the IP of the Windows 10 system*

**Results of SSH attempt (using PuTTY):**

> Network error: Connection timed out

Also, pinging using Fing on my Android phone also is not successful. Fing also does not show the system when I do a scan of the network, although, in the "Recent Hosts" section on Fing, it lists the IP of the Ubuntu server and has its name listed as well, so it had to get that somehow, right?

Comment: Run `ip addr` on your Ubuntu server. Verify that the IP address is really what you expect it to be. Then ping the Ubuntu server. If it fails, show us the complete output. If it succeeds, then try ssh. If connecting via ssh fails, show us the complete output of the attempt.

Comment: I updated the question with the details you asked for. I also verified the IP address on the server and it is 192.168.0.127.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I swear I did this several times already, but I just rebooted my router and access point again and all of a sudden everything is working. I can SSH, ping via IP and name, etc.

Comment: Yes, that happens sometimes.